# make HTML tags inside json response work

Tags: php, json, angularjs, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am retrieving some data from Wikipedia using Wikipedia API as JSON. I am getting html tags along with the data as response. When displaying on browser the html tags are displayed as plain text not as the regular output(I hope I am clear with this sentence). I want to show those as how it should look instead of plain text.following is my PHP code.

```
$url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Sachin_Tendulkar&format=json&redirects&inprop=url&indexpageids';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
echo $json ;
```

Following is the angularJS controller which is used to display the data

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',[]);

demoApp.controller('SimpleController',function ($scope,$http){
$http.post('server/view1.php').success(function(data){
    $scope.info = data;
});
});
```

Comment: I can't see any HTML in http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Sachin_Tendulkar&format=json&explaintext&redirects&inprop=url&indexpageids

Comment: If you're planning on doing anything with it you should at least `json_decode()` it.

Comment: @WayneWhitty Please check now..!! Changed the url

Comment: @BenFortune When I do that it is showing error. no response is coming

Answer (score 2):

In this case:

```
$url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Sachin_Tendulkar&format=json&redirects&inprop=url&indexpageids';
$jsonString = file_get_contents( $url );
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($jsonString, true );
$pageData = $jsonDecoded['query']['pages'][57570]['extract'];
echo $pageData;
```

You need to use the function [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) if you want to interpret JSON data.

Comment: I want the response in JSON since I am using angularJS to display it

Comment: OK, if you look at the edit I made, you'll see that your original JSON string is now in $jsonString, whereas the decoded data is in $jsonDecoded.

Comment: But still I am not geting the response as JSON

Comment: If you're wanting the data in json for angularjs, then why didn't you specify that in your question? You don't even need PHP. `$http.get(etc)`.

Comment: Because I have tried using in $http.get()but geting an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error @BenFortune

Comment: @MdN Have a look at [this](http://better-inter.net/enabling-cors-in-angular-js/) Specifically, `$http.defaults.useXDomain = true;`

Answer (score 0):

You must use `json_decode($json)` to parse response to valid php code.

Comment: When I do that I am getting a fatal error `Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string `

Comment: after json_decode($json) you have php representation of json data. In this case you have object of class stdClass and you can't display it by echo. After decode, check structure by var_dump()